# Storing stock market data

Tags: php, mysql

I have an idea for a virtual stock market game. What I want to do is make each individual stock virtually 'physical', if that makes sense. In my market, users are able to create their own company and they will have 100,000 stocks. The stock price defers on many variables, including some random. My question is, how should I store these individual stocks? For example, lets say Company A currently owns all their stock, each at $120.00. Let's say Company B wants to buy 50,000 of their stocks. Ownership of the stocks has nothing to do with ownership of the company, it merely serves as a way to increase capital. I'm using MySQL as well as PHP. I was thinking of having a separate table called 'stocks', and it would be structured as such:

```
+--Company--+--Price--+--Last Price--+--Owner--+
|     A     |  120.00 |     110.00   |    B    |
+-----------+---------+--------------+---------+
```

And there would be 100,000 rows of this stock. Last price would be used to determine a percentage gain. In my head, this seems perfect. Realistically, the amount of rows that would be inserted into the database would consume massive amounts of data as well as performance. I'm looking for suggestions on how I should implement this feature in a minimized way.

Comment: i cant imagine doing this with out at least a half dozen tables. "including some random" - do you actully know how a real stock market works? there is nothing random in that

Comment: I know how a stock market works, I just don't have many variables to affect the price. "Some random" refers to "random walk hypothesis", which means I multiply the stock price by a random number between 1 - 5 or maybe a smaller range. This is so individual companies stock prices aren't so similar.

Comment: quick question - what determines the price of a stock?

Comment: That would be off-topic. My question isn't what factors go into determining a stocks price, it's how to store each individual stock effectively.

Comment: I'll take that as, you have no idea, good luck with that ;-)

Comment: I have my reasons for not telling. (:

Comment: MySQL is good for relational database management across small to medium table sets. When you want to start talking big tables, you either need huge performance, or a more scalar solution such as cassandra or mongo and of course, nosql.

Comment: If you know the quantity and the price is same why stack all separately, just add a field of quantity. But in the fetching end you may need to do some calculations

Answer (score -1):

You could, in theory, make a multi-dimensional array within PHP, and then JSON encode it and store it in a table with a structure like this:

```
Company|Current Stocks
```

The multi dimensional array could look like this:

```
[[price,owner],[price,owner]...]
```

Then just decode it in PHP whenever you need to access these values.